# Google Analytics Reporting API Dimension Filter regex

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics-api, dimensions

I am trying to create a dimension filter which will return only pagePaths that contain a numeric followed by .html.

To filter for a specific number, I can use: 
&filters=ga:pagePath=@63627877.html

However, I would like to filter for any number.html

I have tried using a regex expression (with a ~), but I don't think that I have the syntax correct.  Any help could be greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: show the regex you already tried

Comment: ah, your problem is not really with the regex, right?

Comment: &filters=ga:pagePath=@~[0-9].html

Comment: I am not sure what the specific problem is.  I am trying to create a filter that does what I described.  I have tried the above filter, and it doesnt work.  It appears that I need to use correct syntax (@ is contains ~ is regex)  I just cant seem to figure out how to code the filter in the GA api

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not correct. Here is how it should be:

`filters=ga:pagePath=~[0-9]+.html$`